# Multiple drupal installations on apache work with their own DNS entries but not with Alias

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, alias

So my localhost server has never had a problem because I've never been developing with other people on multiple websites.

Now, however, accessing a secondary site via an `Alias` is running into a problem as the primary site's (drupal) redirect kicks in and returns a 404. It works fine using a domain from hosts.

The primary site `localhost` is at `~/www`, the secondary site `localhost/second` is at `~/second`

The second site's config file is as such:

```
# Allow lan to access the site without modifying their hosts files
Alias /second /home/j/second

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    # Allow me to access it from domain in hosts file
    ServerName second.local
    # And when I do that undo the alias
    Alias /second /home/j/second/second

    DocumentRoot /home/j/second
    <Directory /home/j/second>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        deny from all
        allow from 192.168.1
        allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

What is actually happening:

- `localhost` should load
  `~/www` and loads
  `~/www`
- `localhost/second` should load
  `~/second` and loads
  `~/second`
- `localhost/second/about` should load
  `~/second/index.php?q=about` but instead loads
  `~/www/index.php?q=second/about`

How do I get it to respond as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You may find a .htaccess file in your drupal site root and look at the rewriterule/rewritebase directives. Your urls are rewritten